# Boot into Yocto using USB bootable drive without installation option

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

I had built a Yocto image from **honister** branch. I created a bootable USB drive and flashed my image into it. Whenever I wanted to boot into the USB drive, I am always given 3 different choice:
`boot`, `install`, `Reboot Into Firmware Interface`

This is a picture of what I see when I boot:

[image]

My question are there any way I can make my yocto image in my USB drive to boot straight into the OS without giving any of those options?
Do I need to make the needed configuration in my already built image or I need to rebuild the image after changing some configuration in my poky or any other meta layers?

Thanks,
Hari

Comment: Please provide more information like, target architecture, what board, or PC (BIOS, UEFI) ??

Comment: https://github.com/edison-fw provides such image for Intel Edison platform, you may check how it's done there.